# How to modify parts of 3D model imported in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I need to find the parts of a 3D model imported in Unreal Engine through fbx importer in order to change something (e.g. a texture, a color, etc.) using Unreal Engine and C++.

I was already able to do so with other open source libraries (e.g. OpenSceneGraph) using the Visitor design pattern to find a pointer to the part and then modifying it but I don't yet know how to do so in Unreal Engine.

Does exist a class to analyze an imported model to find parts? Or is it better to use another approach to modify textures or color of an imported 3D model (e.g. import the parts of the model in an independent manner)?

Answer (score 0):

Generally people reccomended to start poking around the engines FBXImport class since you'll have to homeroll your own FBX conversion code to do anything other than say, change the material during runtime (obvsiously), assuming you mean changing the geometry or such things of an asset thats already been imported.